# how to add and remove <tr> in a HTML table without effect on elements in current view when scrolled on them using jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to add and remove some row  in a table that supports the scrollbar if elements exceed.and when I add or remove some , the current observing be always in the show and prevent them of hiding unless they changed.

https://prnt.sc/s09n7k

as I showed in this picture above link, the elements 1~5 are in a show of monitor with desire scrolled. 0,-1 or 6,7 are hidden in view, and when we remove 0,-1 or 6,7 or when we add another 8th element or -2th element the container has to always show these 1~5 th element that we are scroll on them before and don't affect anything on them unless they themself change.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want "infinite scrolling", I suggest having a look in Google for an infinite scrolling library that will work for you.

It's very hard to implement though and I tend to avoid it in favor of pagination.

There's lots of articles about it:

- https://www.nngroup.com/articles/infinite-scrolling/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/infinite-scrolling-lets-get-to-the-bottom-of-this/

And some libraries out there (amongst others):

- https://infinite-scroll.com/
- https://scrollmagic.io/examples/advanced/infinite_scrolling.html